# Determine the cardinality of $\{B\subseteq A \colon \vert B \vert \leq \kappa \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let $A$ be a set. $\kappa$ a cardinal and assume that $\omega \leq
>  \kappa \leq \vert A \vert \leq 2^{\kappa}$. Determine the cardinality
>   of $C \colon=\{B\subseteq A \colon \vert B \vert \leq \kappa \}$

I have to admit I'm stuck on this one. I got a hint that I should consider well orderings. Cardinals are a subclass of ordinals so they are well ordered under the  relation $|A|\leq |B| \Leftrightarrow$ exists an injection $i\colon A \to B$. So think I can view $C$ at the set of injections into $\kappa$ but I'm not sure how this helps me.

Since $C$ is a subset of the power set of $A$ I can at least establish a upper bound

$$\vert C \vert \leq \vert P(A)\vert = 2^{\vert A \vert} \leq 2^{2^{\kappa} } \geq 2^{2^{\omega} } $$

And since we can define $\phi \colon A \to C, a\mapsto \{a\}$ and $\vert A \vert \geq \omega \implies \vert C \vert \geq \omega$ and then I get no further. My intuition tells me that the cardinality probably is $2^{\kappa}$ but I can't show it.

Any hints, preferably on how do do it with well orderings would be highly appreciated. No full solutions please.

Comment: it seems to me that the answer will depend on $|A|$, right?

Comment: @ForeverMozart Surprisingly, it will not!

Comment: @NoahSchweber oh that is a surprise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint for you. This [almost] has nothing to do with well-ordering. It's about counting, so it's about cardinal arithmetic. And every subset of size at most $\kappa$ has a function from $\kappa$ onto that subset (well, except the empty set). So we're counting functions (modulo some equivalence relation).

Try to calculate first the case where $A=\kappa$, or $A=2^\kappa$. Then see that anything in between must have the same result. For a specific case, try to take the case where $\kappa=\aleph_0$. This is a classical result, and we use it, for example, when we count how many continuous functions are there from $\Bbb R$ to itself.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.

Comment: @Noah: And I was just on my out to grab a beer and do some math. Fancy that! :P